# Writing in an existing file using streamwriter

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I want to use StreamWriter to write in a file that already exists in my project's debug folder. How can I do that? I thought StreamWriter can only write to a whole new file.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean append?

```
 StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("abc.txt", true);
 sw.WriteLine("test");
 sw.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using(var sw = new StreamWriter("yourfile.txt", true))//default location is your bin folder
{
}
```

Use the above overload